# Where I can get the OpenGL Libraries?

Tags: opengl

OpenGL Libraries and header files are
• opengl32.lib
• glu32.lib
• gl.h
• glu.h

where i can get these files ?

Comment: A lack of googling does not warrant a -1, since google will find this answer shortly. So, +1, taking this out of the negative (at least for now). Surely, any question can be answered by reading a book or doing a more complex search, but then what of SO? What need does it fill? Its related, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the header and library files that are shipped by default (at least with Visual Studio) are not that helpful, especially is you plan to use 'modern' OpenGL features or extensions.

You should take a look at [cross-platform extension loading libraries](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/).

Answer (score 1):

That should be included in your compiler. g++ ships them (as far as I know), MSVC too.

What exactly is your compiler / operating system / programming language?

edit: see if that works:

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
```

edit2: You should rethink how you ask the question, plus which tags you select. \rant

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio you need the platformsdk. It comes with the Visual Studio CD (at least pro) but you will need to download it separately if you are using the express download.

Answer (score 0):

All these files you have mentioned are parts of compiler's headers and libraries and are shiped with any one you're using. They do present both in gcc and visual studio compilers.

You just use 'em like that:

```
// for any compiler
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

// VisualStudio-specific
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
```

With GNU compiler you should pass linker args like this (taken from opengl.org):

> -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lX11

Hope this will help =)